# Script tag messes my website up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As the title describes, i cannot understand the reason why, by adding this line at the bottom of my page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
```

my website messes up.

The code at the end of my file is this

```
    </div><!-- /.center -->

    <!-- add new calendar event modal -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <!-- Bootstrap WYSIHTML5 -->
    <script src="js/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- AdminLTE App -->
    <script src="js/AdminLTE/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- here --><script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Usename Availability -->
```

and by adding the line above, exactly below the

`<!--AdminLTE App-->`

my website changes height and it becomes shorter like in the photos below. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You already have a jquery included. Why include it again?

Comment: Well, you are including an older version of jQuery at the end of everything, this causing problems of course. Just do not do it : )) [and check if any of the other libs require a specific version of jQuery].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you putting 2 jquery files?

You already have jquery version 2.1.1

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and then you want to put an older jquery version of 1.2.6. This can mess things up. Since you put the 1.2.6 version at the very bottom, it is the one that will be used to render your page instead of the 2.1.1 version.

Have you tried not to attach this 1.2.6 version in the bottom? Does it work okay? If yes, means the older version does not support the elements you are trying to work with.

In response to your comment about your script for real time username validation not working unless 1.2.6 is included, it seems that that's the case... however, you can use no conflict jquery before your username availability section as such:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script> var jq126 = jQuery.noConflict(); </script>

<!-- Usename Availability -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--

    pic1 = new Image(16, 16); 
    pic1.src = "loader.gif";

    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#username").change(function() { 

    var usr = $("#username").val();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In future, please edit your post to add additional information, or to respond to comments, rather than posting new answers!